# get the browser's sceen height, when the console is open

Tags: javascript

in order to get the browser's screen height,

`window.innerHeight` in js and
`$(window).height()` in jquery is used.

i have a modal(popup) which i calculate and refresh it's position(i make it center aligned) when it's inner html is changed.

so first i need to compare the modal's new height to the browser screen's height before positioning.

Problem:
the problem i have is that when the browser's console is open, the code above doesn't give me the browsers screen height, i gives a much less number

browser height is less when console is opened

[image]

Comment: when you open you console your window's height shrinks,maybe you can get your body.scrollHeight

Answer (score 0):

To find the entire height,

```
window.outerHeight
```

or

```
screen.availHeight
```

can be used. This will not consider the console size.